# Getting ValidationException for Dynamodb in Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, crud

I've made a schema like this~

```
type Movie struct {
    Year         int    `json:"year"`
    Title        string `json:"title"`
    Key          string `json:"userId"`
    Email        string `json:"email"`
    Bio          string `json:"bio"`
    Number       int    `json:"phoneNumber"`
    SocialHandle string `json:"socialHandle"`
    Onboarding   string `json:"username"`
    BankDetails  string `json:"bankDetails"`
    Image        string `json:"image"`
    Password     string `json:"password"`
    Resume       string `json:"resume"`
    Pincode      string `json:"pinCode"`
}
```

Here Key and onboarding are my primary and sorting keys respectively. Then I added data like this~

```
movie := Movie{
    Key:        "2323",
    Onboarding: "The Big New Movie",
}
```

Then a normal MarshalMap of the thing I made, and used the data to get the item.

```
key, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(movie)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
    Key:       key,
    TableName: aws.String("tablename"),
}

result, err := svc.GetItem(input)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

The weird thing being I inserted data using the same code with few changes, but while fetching data it shows error ~ ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: Can you share the output of `DeacribeTable` for your table?

Comment: @LeeHannigan AttributeDefinitions: [{
        AttributeName: "userId",
        AttributeType: "S"
      },{
        AttributeName: "username",
        AttributeType: "S"
      }], even though I've inserted 4-5 data with more names of column

Comment: Your Movie struct doesn't contain userId or username, so that's why it's complaining. That schema is based on the Primary Key and Sort key you set when you created the table. You probably need to recreate your table with PK/SK matching your Movie schema.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson movie := Movie{
  Key:        "23g23",
  Year:       2015,
  Title:      "The Big New Movie",
  Onboarding: "Fdsfsd",
 }, the Movie struct I described consists of the key username and userId, apart from that when I query like this too issue still arises.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson I think I can only have keys that are present in the schema otherwise the search won't return. Meaning no extra key is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is likely caused by sending non-key attributes in the GetItem call. When you use MarshalMap, it is including a null value for all other attributes in the key object.

Either you can construct the key manually:

```
Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
  "userId": {
    S: aws.String("2323"),
  },
  "username": {
    S: aws.String("The Big New Movie"),
  },
},
```

Or add omitempty to the struct fields, which will exclude these attributes from the marshalled map when they have no value:

```
type Movie struct {
    Year         int    `json:"year,omitempty"`
    Title        string `json:"title,omitempty"`
        [...]
}
```

Comment: I tried during the same, i.e, omitempty, but when I when I search with primary key, sort key and any third param,like email or stuff, it throws the same error.

Comment: You cannot search for all values in a GetItem request, you must only provide the primary key, made up of Partition and optional Sort keys.